# Is powershell able to provide IP address from host name if possibly not on network anymore?

Tags: powershell, ip, hostname

I'm trying to take a list and ping every hostname in the textfile to get the ip address. I've tried several ways from ping, nslookup, etc. I was able to get further using a batch script/command line to get it down to using ping since ping on there will still display the IP address even if cannot get a response where as powershell just states it cannot resolve with the computer name (hostname). Any thoughts?

Comment: please ... post the code you tried, what the response was, and what you want done differently.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, why are you trying to find IP addresses from hostnames via ping? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Using `ping.exe` (with the same args) (c/sh)ouldn't differ between PowerShell and cmd line/batch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on the network or the DNS does not hold the record then no you can not get the IP from Hostname.

If you are on the other hand on the network or the DNS has it then you can use

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName("google-public-dns-a.google.com").AddressList |  %{
    $_.IPAddressToString
}
```

Returns `8.8.8.8`

Or if you wanted to get Hostname from IP

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("8.8.8.8").Hostname
```

Returns `google-public-dns-a.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($server).addresslist | % { ("Server $server IP: " + $_.IPAddressToString) }
```